# Pull name from one table unless row exists in another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.Nome, ...
FROM cadClientes as a 
...
join Contatos_Clientes as f on a.id = f.idCliente
```

The problem is that sometimes there isn't a row in `Contatos_Clientes`.

I want to return `Nome` from `Contatos_Clientes` if it exists, otherwise return `Nome` from `cadClientes`.

Comment: Please look into `OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Aaron Bertrand, Thanks a lot. Left Join solved my problem. You plz post an awnser so I can accept it.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to show values from one table only when they don't exist in another, you should change the join to a LEFT OUTER JOIN. Example:

```
SELECT Nome = COALESCE(c.Nome, cc.Nome) -- ,... Other columns
FROM dbo.cadClientes AS c
-- other joins...
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Contatos_Clientes AS cc
ON c.id = cc.idCliente;
```

Please always use the schema prefix when creating / referencing objects, and try to use meaningful aliases instead of a,b,c...